# jQuery .select works, but Javascript .select doesnt

Tags: javascript, jquery, windows-mobile, internet-explorer-6

I am building a mobile site for a Motorola / IE 6 device.

For some reason that I can not come up with, jQuery's .select() function is working, but directly calling it in javascript is not.

```
<input type="text" id="lid" value="" class="as_done">
```

The jQuery way that works is this:

```
$('#lid').select();
```

The way that isn't working is this:

```
document.getElementById('lid').select();
```

---

This has me all sorts of confused. Any ideas as to why this is?

EDIT: I am not trying to do anything in jQuery. I am just trying to select the text inside the input box. I shouldn't need jQuery to do this, but the standard way is not working. http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_text_select.asp

Comment: it does work ->  http://jsfiddle.net/e3EKv/

Comment: that fiddle does not work in firefox [Isaac Fife](http://stackoverflow.com/users/803876/isaac-fife)... I assume it does work in Webkit browsers... EDIT: does work in Chrome

Comment: Notice the windows-mobile / IE 6...

Comment: checkout my answer below and try to natively focus the input before calling the native select

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Interesting change made it work for me. Perhaps this is a bug in windows mobile IE 6?

Consider the following html:

```
<input type="hidden" id="lid_as" name="lid" value="1">
<input type="text" id="lid" value="" class="as_done">
```

Calling `alert("document.getElementById('lid').name");` resulted in the message `lid`. This makes me think that it is grabbing the first input box whose ID is actually lid_as.

When I moved the `lid_as` input below the `lid` box, the `select` function works properly.

So this HTML made it work:

```
<input type="text" id="lid" value="" class="as_done">
<input type="hidden" id="lid_as" name="lid" value="1">
```

Again, this question is in relation to WINDOWS MOBILE IE 6.

Comment: seeing this [link](http://www.456bereastreet.com/archive/200802/beware_of_id_and_name_attribute_mixups_when_using_getelementbyid_in_internet_explorer/) ... I think it is a known bug that ID and NAME could both be used or are replacing each other

Comment: @TobiasKrogh , I just googled and found that link too. I was pulling my hair out for a bit there... Bah.

Answer (score 1):

$() function returns a jquery object whereas document.getElementById returns a simple DOM object.

Answer (score 0):

maybe it happens due to the fact you did not call .focus() in advance

```
document.getElementById('lid').focus();
document.getElementById('lid').select();
```

this is wrapped in jQuerys .select()

Comment: I did try this, but it didn't change the result. However, I posted an answer as to what fixed it for me. I think it's a mobile browser glitch.

Comment: I see `Property 'select' does not exist on type 'HTMLElement'. Did you mean 'onselect'`

Comment: @AlexanderMills depends on what type of HTMLElement you are selecting. The method exists on elements that take input e.g. [HTMLInputElement.select](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLInputElement/select) - also HTMLTextAreaElement - but does not exist on every HTMLElement